# Getting the Percentage of two variables

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, math, while-loop

I have tried using casting with my variables as well as some of the other tips that I have read on here about getting percentages and its not working here is the code. There is a lot more to it, of course. I have tried all ways from casting, to what I have displayed.

> (EDITED AGAIN 2nd time)

Here is the whole code. You were right is was working but in this, it is not! Even if the grade variables are `float` or `int`, still not working. Changed the grade variables so they don't display a decimal!. Output (BELOW) shows the grade but not the percentage. Thanks for the feedback.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Please enter a grade from 0 - 100! Enter -1 to end the program! 99 
Please enter a grade from 0 - 100! Enter -1 to end the program! -1 
The total number of grades is 2 
Number of A's = 1 which is %0.0 
Number of B's = 0 which is %0.0 
Number of C's = 0 which is %0.0 
Number of D's = 0 which is %0.0 
Number of F's = 0 which is %0.0
```

**Code:**
    public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] main) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;

    int totalGrades = 1 ;

    int gradeA = 0 ;
    float gradeAPercentage = (gradeA * 100f) / totalGrades ; 

    int gradeB = 0 ;
    float gradeBPercentage = gradeB / totalGrades ;

    int gradeC = 0 ;
    float gradeCPercentage = gradeC / totalGrades ;

    int gradeD = 0 ;
    float gradeDPercentage = gradeD / totalGrades ;

    int gradeF = 0 ;
    float gradeFPercentage = gradeF / totalGrades ;

    int a = 0 ;

    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter a grade from 0 - 100! Enter -1 to end the program!") ;
        int grade = input.nextInt() ;

        if( (grade == -1) && (totalGrades == 0) ) {
            System.out.println("You entered no grades!") ;
            totalGrades--;
            break ;
        } 
        else if(grade == -1){
            a++ ;
        }
        else if(grade <= 59){
            gradeF++ ;
            totalGrades++ ;
        }
        else if( (grade >= 60) && (grade <= 69) ){
            gradeD++ ;
            totalGrades++ ;
        }
        else if( (grade >= 70) && (grade <= 79) ){
            gradeC++ ;
            totalGrades++ ;
        }
        else if( (grade >= 80) && (grade <= 89) ){
            gradeB++ ;
            totalGrades++ ;
        }
        else if( (grade <= 100) && (grade >= 90) ){
            gradeA++ ;
            totalGrades++ ;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Your input is Invalid") ;
            continue ;
        }
    }while(a < 1 ) ;

    System.out.println("The total number of grades is " + totalGrades) ;
    System.out.println("Number of A's = " + gradeA + " which is %" + gradeAPercentage) ;
    System.out.println("Number of B's = " + gradeB + " which is %" + gradeBPercentage) ;
    System.out.println("Number of C's = " + gradeC + " which is %" + gradeCPercentage) ;
    System.out.println("Number of D's = " + gradeD + " which is %" + gradeDPercentage) ;
    System.out.println("Number of F's = " + gradeF + " which is %" + gradeFPercentage) ;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including a class and a `main()` function. Be sure to include code that produces output. Then show the output and tell us how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: `int totalGrades = 5 ;

      float gradeA = 0.12f ;
      float gradeAPercentage = (gradeA * 100.0f) / totalGrades ; 
      System.out.println(gradeAPercentage);` works OK as it is

Comment: p.s. The code you have here performs the calculation correctly.

Comment: You are making variables like `gradeAPercentage` before getting any input, then printing them at the end without ever doing anything to them. They are also all the same - `gradeAPercentage = (gradeA * 100f) / totalGrades;` becomes `0 * 100 / 1` which is always `0`.

Comment: I'm confused; you set a variable to `0` then divide by a number. `0 / anything` is always `0`.

Comment: @csmckelvey should the iteration in the while loops add one to the variable though!

Comment: It will, but then _after_ the loop is done you need to do the percentage calculations with those new values. If you do `gradeBPercentage = gradeB / totalGrades;` and then later on change `gradeB` or `totalGrades`, that doesn't affect `gradeBPercentage` as it has already been given a value previously.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit casting done, no additional casting to float is needed. The code you provided works fine. If you print the result with

```
System.out.println(gradeAPercentage);
```

you will get, what you have wanted to calculate.